# Can't install Ruby on updated OS X Mavericks

Tags: ruby, xcode, osx-mavericks, ruby-1.9

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.2 so that I can take an online course in Ruby. I just upgraded by OSX to Mavericks (10.9.1) so that I could install the latest version of XCode (5.0.2), that is now also installed.

I'm sure I must be missing something basic here. Can anybody take a look at my Terminal install log and error messages here an help me out? I appreciate any thoughts.

```
dave-morans-macbook:~ davemoran$ rvm install 1.9.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
It is not possible to build movable binaries for rubies 1.8-1.9.2, but you can do it for your system only.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing macports...
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_install_port',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/davemoran/.rvm/log/1389714845_ruby-1.9.2-p320/port_install.log
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking MacPorts version... 2.2.1
checking for sw_vers... /usr/bin/sw_vers
checking for defaults... /usr/bin/defaults
checking for xcode-select... /usr/bin/xcode-select
checking Mac OS X version... 10.9.1
checking Xcode location... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
checking Xcode version... 5.0.2
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/davemoran/.rvm/src/MacPorts-2.2.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
Requirements installation failed with status: 77.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what finally worked for me on OSX 10.9.3 with Xcode 5.1.1 (5B1008)

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
```

**Edit**: The above command can also be supplemented with additional options. I pulled these options from the command output of the prior failed installation

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.6:/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.6:/usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.0:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to install the command line tools for Xcode.

You could also try adding `--with-gcc=gcc-4.2` to the end of your rvm command above.

Comment: I tried it like this: "rvm install 1.9.2 --with-gcc=gcc-4.2"
And got this: "You requested building with 'gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path." I'm again guessing I may have entered the commands incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing command line tools for Xcode. You can install them from `Xcode-> Preferences-> Downloads`, or from the command line with `xcode-select --install`.

Try the rvm install after installing the command line tools.

Comment: Thank you. There was no command line tools downloads available when I looked in the Downloads preference pane of Xcode itself, so I tried doing as you suggested, xammy, and went right from the command line itself in terminal. Everything launched properly, I agreed to the terms in Xcode and then got this error message in the Command Line Developer Tools installer: "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server."

Comment: There seems to be some issue with Xcode 5.2 & command line tools. So while they might have installed the required components, they would still show that error. Can you share the output of "gcc --version".

Comment: i'm seeing this too

Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors when I was trying to install an older ruby `(2.0.0p247)` on OSX Mavericks, and this is what worked for me:

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0-p247 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr --disable-binary  --with-gcc=gcc-4.2
```

HTH,
Florin.